# Is there any way to delete App ID when IOS Developer Program expired?

Tags: ios

My IOS dev program has expired: [Expiration Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cDdp.png)

I want to delete an App Id in that expired account and use that deleted app id in another account I have. So,

1. Is it possible to create an App Id which was created and deleted in different account before (any app with that app id not published on App Store before)?
2. Is there any way to delete an App Id while my developer program expires.

Comment: I would phone the apple dev support staff and tell them your problem: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the details of how Apple's developer program works, and is better directed to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Apple's technical support is unavailable from December 23, 2014 to January 4, 2015 because of the Christmas.
I looking for a solution on their forums right now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldnt be worry about App ID's, they are local to account. Bundle ID is something which is required to be unique to put app on Apple store.